# Converting a C# snippit to Java

Tags: c#, java

The Java code should have the same functionality as the C# code.  Is this code the same?

This is the code in C# code:

```
byte[] hashBytes;
UnicodeEncoding encoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
hashBytes = encoding.GetBytes(inputstr.Text.ToUpper().Trim());

SHA1 sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] cryptPassword = sha1.ComputeHash(hashBytes);
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
SHA1.Text = enc.GetString(cryptPassword);
outputstr.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(cryptPassword);
```

Here is the Java ported code, but I'm getting different output:

```
byte[] pwBytes = new String("password".toUpperCase().getBytes(), "UTF-16").getBytes();

MessageDigest md = null;
md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] sha1pw = md.digest(pwBytes);

final BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
String encodedPw = encoder.encode(sha1pw);
```

The Java code should calculate encodedPw the same way that the C# code calculates outputstr.Text.

I'm sorry, I can not run the C# code to provide an example.  The Java code hashes "password" as `oghZbO1T3U/eu3POLIIQweZ/gvQ=`.

Comment: Can you show us the different output?

Comment: sorry, the example is the password so I can not provide it.  I have edited the question.

Comment: So are you saying the two pieces of code above with the password "password" *do* produce the same correct output?

Comment: Someone provided the C# code to me and the final hash.  I used the password in the Java code but got a different hash.  The Java code will hash "password" (no quotes) as `oghZbO1T3U/eu3POLIIQweZ/gvQ=` .. I can not run the C# code though.

Comment: Please update this question to be generally applicable to other users on the internet. We don't help people translate "random" code snippets from one language to another. We want questions that are searchable and will be useful for someone else that has that same need.

Comment: If you know the C# code is valid, then you should disregard whatever hash they told you it was supposed to produce -- especially if they didn't bother to tell you what the original password was.  Instead, run the C# code and get the output of some password like "password" and then compare that output to what you obtain when running the Java code with the same password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnicodeEncoding` uses [UTF-16 little endian in c#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hs5kkbk.aspx) by default, whereas `UTF-16` in java is big endian by default. So in Java you would need:

```
byte[] pwBytes = "password".toUpperCase().getBytes("UTF-16LE");
```

Comment: That definitely made a difference.  I will verify and accept this answer asap.  thank you...

Comment: It works.  I'll point out the the LE is required.  Also, my code in calling getBytes twice was completely wrong too.

Comment: @jcalfee314 Also note that in your original code, you call `getBytes()` which uses the default charset on your machine. The part where you use `UTF-16` is used to create the string only, not the array of bytes.